# Trying to model the ball and beam problem

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am trying to model the well-known ball and beam problem with Modelica. Now I have struggle to model the ball rolling down an inclined plane depending on the angle. I intended to use the MultiBody libraray. Has anybody an idea how to handle that? Or has anybody dealt with a similar problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For hints and reference you might take a look at the simple vehicle model in the MSL translational package:

```
Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Components.Vehicle
```

Check out how the inclined plane is implemented with `idealRollingWheel` to calculate gravity based acceleration on the vehicle.
Slight modification of that should deliver what you require for your tilted plane.

`MultiBody` provides a `Wheel` as well, but since you are investigating a 2D scenario keeping things simple might be helpful.